# Image file name stored in array then displayed through loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've correctly did this with displaying text in a p tag but i can't figure out why my image won't show up in the same manner and I'm not sure if it has to do with how it was set up in html.

```
let imgArray = ["beastiary.jpg"];

window.addEventListener("load", showImages);

function showImages() {
    let i = 0;

    let images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

    while (i < imgArray.length) {
        images[i].innerHTML = imgArray[i]

        i++
    }

}
```

```
 <div class="w3-col m3 l3 " style="padding-right: 5px">
                        <div class="w3-card-4 w3-theme-l1" id="book">
                           <img src="" alt="book">
                            <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-theme-d3">
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

I have tried to do away with using img and instead put it in a div using an id but it still won't show up. There will be more images I'm just making sure this one works first before I start adding the rest.

Comment: You need to set `src`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For showing image you need to set src to proper url

```js
let imgArray = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/800px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"];

window.addEventListener("load", showImages);

function showImages() {
  let i = 0;

  let images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

  while (i < imgArray.length) {
    images[i].src = imgArray[i]
    i++
  }

}
```

```css
.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img class='img'/>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this now I understand what I  was doing wrong.